# Why there are two "is" in one sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

There is no simple rule for inventory turnover, except that a high ratio is preferable provided inventory is adequate to meet demand

Comment: Your question title is not clear, you can edit it.

Comment: There are three.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple rule for inventory turnover, except that a high ratio is preferable **provided** inventory is adequate to meet demand.

provided:

> conj also **provided that**
>   used to say that something will only be possible if something else happens or is done
>
> = providing
>
> He can come with us, provided he pays for his own meals.

The last "is" is inside a subordinate clause starting with the conjunction "provided".